# how to find id using jquery with complex html?

Tags: jquery

How to get `div45452314234` if i click on `Share on Facebook

```
<div id="div45452314234" class="Display">Display</div>
    <div class="Actions">
        <span>
            <div id="count">0</div>
            <a>Like</a>
        </span> 
        <span class="Author">Author</span>
        <span class="Recency">Recency</span> |
        <span><a class="ShareFB"  href="">Share on Facebook</a></span> |
        <span><a href="">Share on Twitter</a></span> |
    </div>
```

heck out here :-

> http://jsfiddle.net/WLS5T/

Answer (score 2):

This will get you what you need...

```
$(function() {
    $(".ShareFB").on("click", function() {
        var $div = $(this).closest(".Actions").prev();
        alert($div.attr('id'));
    });
});
```

`closest()` will parse back up the DOM tree until it finds the first instance of an element with the class `Actions` and then `prev()` will select the previous element.  `$div` will then be a jQuery object that you can use as you wish.

**Edit**

I've updated your fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/WLS5T/1/

One problem was the call to ShareFB which was stopping the rest of the script running, and I fixed my previously incorrect code as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.ShareFB').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().parent().prev().attr("id"));
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use recursion.

```
function getTargetParent(node){
if($(node).attr('class')=='Actions'){
    alert($(node).prev().attr('id'));
}
 getTargetParent($(node).parent());
return;
}

 var targnode=$('.Actions').find('.ShareFB');//replace with $(this) in real scenario
 getTargetParent(targnode);
```

See this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/tAssd/

Comment: If you want to return the value instead you can use this. http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/eQFjJ/1/

Comment: I'm unsure that the OP 'needs' to use recursion for a simple task as this.

Comment: Ya using existing library is better idea but working with things in low level is always better when you need fine tuning.

Comment: machikne randi ka baan haru. mero lado kha muji haru.